# Propositional calculus help proving theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am asked to prove:

(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ (Y ∧ X) => (Z ∧ X) ≡ X

What I have done:

(¬Y V Z) ∧ X

(X ∧ ¬Y) V (X ∧ Z)

I don't know where to go from there. I would sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you add more grouping symbols (parentheses)? It isn't clear to me what the precedence of the $\equiv$ and $\Rightarrow$ operators is. Is the outermost statement the implication?

Comment: Yes, no problem. ((Y => Z) ∧ X) ≡ ((Y ∧ X) => (Z ∧ X)) ≡ X

Comment: Start with a double negation of term 1 and term 2 and try to get X. I think you would also need De Morgan's laws.

Comment: So this is a compound statement of the form $A\equiv B \equiv C$. Formally, you need another set of parentheses since these are binary operators

Comment: I understood it an an implication to prove ...

Comment: IMHO   => is stronger than ≡ ... I guess this is the reason why there are no parentheses ... I understood itr as prove if (A ≡ B) => (C ≡ D)

Comment: It's right that '$\Rightarrow$' is stronger, that should be connect first i.e. $A\equiv B\Rightarrow C\equiv D$ means $A\equiv (B\Rightarrow C)\equiv D$, but actually the statement in question hold for both interpretation

Answer (score 1):

To prove: **(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ (Y ∧ X) => (Z ∧ X) ≡ X**

step one using double negation

(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ ¬(¬((Y => Z) ∧ X))

step two using De Morgan's laws

(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ ¬(¬(Y => Z) V ¬X )

step three using the negation of an implication

(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ ¬((Y ∧ ¬Z) V ¬X )

step four using De Morgan's laws again

(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ ¬(Y ∧ ¬Z) ∧ X)

step five using De Morgan's laws again

(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ (¬Y V Z) ∧ X :(1)

**Now:**

(Y => Z) ∧ X ≡ (Y ∧ X) => (¬Y V Z) ∧ X ≡ Y ∧ X => (¬Y ∧ X) V (Z ∧ X)  ≡ Y ∧ X

This means that  Y ∧ [(¬Y ∧ X) V (Z ∧ X)]  ≡ Y ∧ (Y ∧ X)

=> (Y ∧ (¬Y ∧ X)) V (Y ∧ (Z ∧ X))  ≡ Y ∧ X =>  (Y ∧ (Z ∧ X))  ≡ Y ∧ X

=>  **Z ∧ X  ≡ X** **Proved!**

Source: https://www.tu-ilmenau.de/fileadmin/media/num/neundorf/Dokumente/Lehre/hm/Aussagen_Wertetafel.pdf